# What does 'performance' mean in the passage?

Tags: meaning

What does ***'performance'*** in the passage exactly mean?  I assume it is not used as its general meaning.

> "The analogies between science and art are very good as long as you
>   are talking about the creation and **the performance**. The creation is
>   certainly very analogous. The aesthetic pleasure of the craftsmanship
>   of **performance** is also very strong in science." - Freeman Dyson

Comment: Why do you think like that? To me, a learner, craftsmanship of performance means all the things a person may engineer to give a specific feeling to their audience through their performance.

Answer (score 1):

Performance meaning "the act of doing something".

> The police officer was shot in the performance of his duties.

(meaning, while he was doing his duties as a police officer)

Dyson is making the point that there is pleasure in doing science well, just as there is pleasure in doing art well.  The scientist enjoys doing an elegant experiment just as the musician enjoys playing her trumpet beautifully.